# How to encrypt a .bin file

Tags: python, encryption

I need to encrypt 3 `.bin` files which contain 2 keys for Diffie-Hellman. I have no clue how to do that, all I could think of was what I did in the following Python file. I have an example what the output should look like but my code doesn't seem to produce the right keys. The output file `server.ini` is used by a client to connect to a server.

```
import base64

fileList = [['game_key.bin', 'Game'], ['gate_key.bin', 'Gate'], ['auth_key.bin', 'Auth']]
iniList = []
for i in fileList:
    file = open(i[0], 'rb')
    n = list(file.read(64))
    x = list(file.read(64))
    file.close()
    n.reverse()
    x.reverse()
    iniList.append(['Server.' + i[1] + '.N "' + base64.b64encode("".join(n)) + '"\n', 'Server.' + i[1] + '.X "' + base64.b64encode("".join(x)) + '"\n'])
iniList[0].append('\n')

#time for user Input

ip = '"' + raw_input('Hostname: ') + '"'
dispName = 'Server.DispName ' + '"' + raw_input('DispName: ') + '"' + '\n'
statusUrl = 'Server.Status ' + '"' + raw_input('Status URL: ') + '"' + '\n'
signupUrl = 'Server.Signup ' + '"' + raw_input('Signup URL: ') + '"' + '\n'

for l in range(1, 3):
    iniList[l].append('Server.' + fileList[l][1] + '.Host ' + ip + '\n\n')

for l in [[dispName], [statusUrl], [signupUrl]]:
    iniList.append(l)

outFile = open('server.ini', 'w')

for l in iniList:
    for i in l:
        outFile.write(i)

outFile.close()
```

The following was in my example file:

```
# Keys are Base64-encoded 512 bit RC4 keys, as generated by DirtSand's keygen
# command.  Note that they MUST be quoted in the commands below, or the client
# won't parse them correctly!
```

I also tried it without inverting `n` and `x`

Comment: There is no encryption in the code.

Comment: Okay then I guess I need to convert the .bin files which are already encoded so my client accepts them.

Comment: You can use the PHP mcrypt function, without padding since the file sizes are a multiple of block size. You will need to have a good encryption key (not a password string) and random iv. But then you need to keep secret the encryption key, that essentially trade one problem for another.  Depending  on how you will transfer the keys it may get more complicated. It is not as an easy problem as it may seem to be.

Comment: Okay thanks for your help, I guess I'm telling you wrong things as I don't really know what the real problem is (or what I'm doing). Maybe I need to ask someone who knows what the .bin are I need to convert/encrypt.